# Is there any way to extract header and footer and title page of a PDF document?

Tags: python, pdf, text-mining

I want to know if there is any package to detect and extrac the header and footer or title page from PDF document ? I am new in text mining using python and I want to know for example pdfminer.layout could help to find any text block in pdfs?

Comment: There is `pdfminer`, just give it a search and you will find a lot of information

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apache Tika also does metadata extraction. You can also extract names, title/multiple-titles, date, number of pages, modified dates, and many more.

```
import tika
from tika import parser

filename = "your file name here"
parsedPDF = parser.from_file(file_name)
print(parsedPDF['content'])
print(parsedPDF['metadata']) # its in a dictionary format.
```

Comment: not seeing where the header / footer extraction is here

Comment: You have to look at the dictionary contents. I used this library for published white papers. From what I have seen, if there is header or footer, it picks it up and puts into a  {key,value} pair.

Comment: Ok. It didn't do that for me so I guess it only works when those are tagged in a specific way in the original PDF.

Comment: This answer needs improvement, it does not tell where the header/footer extraction is taking place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this utility function to extract all text elements from PDF:

```
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextLine
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter, PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage, PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser


def pdf2text(stream):
    parser = PDFParser(stream)
    document = PDFDocument(parser)
    if not document.is_extractable:
        raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed

    resmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = PDFPageAggregator(resmgr, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resmgr, device)
    for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        for obj in device.get_result():
            if isinstance(obj, (LTTextBox, LTTextLine)):
                yield obj.get_text()
```

`stream` parameter is a file-like object (e.g. file opened for reading or an instance of `io.BytesIO` or such).

This example basically follows [official example](https://euske.github.io/pdfminer/programming.html).

Comment: I need to extract the header and footer to find the name of document author , as I undertood LTTextBox could help to find the block in text? Could you please explain more ?I'm very confused , Thanks .

Comment: Could you give an example PDF? I'm afraid there is no general guide.

Comment: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pdfminer-docs/latest/pdfminer-docs.pdf

Comment: fo example if I want extract the name of document from header or footer (pdfminer, Release 0.0.1)

Comment: I'm not aware that this would be possible in any natural way with PDFMiner, as it treats all the text the same - it doesn't distinguish title from header or footer. You have to leverage your knowledge of the document structure yourself and parse the text e.g. using regular expressions (that's what I usually do).