# Extract header and footer from pdf in python

Tags: python, pdfminer

I have read a pdf using `pdfminer`. I want to detect the header and footer of the pdf. Please let me know if there is any possibility.

Comment: Sample I/O with your efforts that did not work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306295/is-there-any-way-to-extract-header-and-footer-and-title-page-of-a-pdf-document?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also possible with Apache Tika:

```
import tika
from tika import parser

FileName = "PDF File Name"
PDF_Parse = parser.from_file(FileName)
print(PDF_Parse ['content'])
print(PDF_Parse ['metadata']) # Format-Dictionary
```