# is there any way to extract content of pdf header and footer using pypdf2 or any other tool

Tags: python, pypdf, pdftotext

`i want to check is there any header or footer in a pdf by using python if possible using pypdf2 or any other python tool i have already checked one answer form over stackover flow liknk :`[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306295/is-there-any-way-to-extract-header-and-footer-and-title-page-of-a-pdf-document)
 `If there is header and footer also i want ot extract content of that header and footer`
`Here i am using one methos using pypdf2 that showing some error`

```
header = False
        footer = False
        try:
            header_height = reader.pages(page_number).extract_text().index(page.extract_text()[:100]) / page.width
            if header_height > 0.01:
                header = True
        except ValueError:
            pass

        try:
            footer_height = reader.pages(page_number).extract_text().index(page.extract_text()[-100:]) / page.width
            if footer_height < 0.99:
                footer = True
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

`but this showing :  in detect_boundary`

````
TypeError: '_VirtualList' object is not callable```

`this error   PLEASE HELP ME I WILL BE THANKFUL TO YOU ` 
`thsi i tried to solve using chatgpt but it is unable to help suggest me this:`
````

The error message `TypeError: '_VirtualList' object is not callable` suggests that you are trying to call a method or function on an object of type `_VirtualList`, which is not allowed.

To resolve this error, you should review your code and check where you are trying to call a method or function on the `_VirtualList` object. Make sure you are using the correct syntax and accessing the methods or properties of the object properly.

Without seeing the specific code that is causing the error, it is challenging to provide a more specific solution. However, here are a few general troubleshooting steps you can follow:

1. Check the object type: Make sure the object you are trying to call a method or function on is indeed an instance of the expected class or type. Double-check your variable assignments and ensure that the object is being assigned correctly.
2. Review the documentation: If you are using a library or framework, consult the documentation to understand the correct usage and available methods for the objects you are working with. Look for any examples or guidelines provided by the library.
3. Debugging: Insert print statements or use a debugger to inspect the object and its attributes at the point of error. This can help you identify any issues with the object's state or how it is being accessed in your code.
4. Verify the version: Ensure that you are using the correct version of the library or package that is compatible with your code. Sometimes, outdated or incompatible versions can cause unexpected errors.

By following these steps and closely examining your code, you should be able to identify the specific issue causing the `_VirtualList` error and resolve it accordingly.```

possible anything by which I can solve this problem any article, code with some explanation_jaishreemahakal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: '_VirtualList' object is not callable

Comes from

```
reader.pages(page_number)
```

It should be:

```
reader.pages[PAGE_NUMBER]
```

Comment: dear thoma that is working fine but also now that starts working and the  code is here

Comment: I have no idea what you want to tell me.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2. I can tell you (1) you should use pypdf and not PyPDF2 (2) reader.pages is not callable, but implements the list interface. Your code is for sure broken

Comment: Ok I will go with pypdf today I will try with that and is i will get back to you whatever will be the result and thankyou.

Comment: Dear Thoma, i wanted to ask you that is there any specific property by which we can get directly check that any pdf page has header of footer of not. like by meadiabox we can get height and width.

Comment: No, there is no simple way to check / get the header/footer of pages. Not in pypdf and not in any other PDF library. The reason is that PDF does not distinguish between header/footer and the rest of the content (in most cases at least; there are tagged PDFs but I'm uncertain how wide-spread they are)